# IE 10 does not accept the <li> tag type attribute's custom value

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-10, custom-attributes

My site is developed with HTML5 and CSS3.

The Custom value is assigned in `<li>` tag type attribute.

My problem is, IE 10 does not accept the custom value for type attribute. So its throwing the error and not loading the `<ul>` content. There is no issues on other browsers.

Is there any way to make it work in IE 10.

Sorry. Here is the code. The `<li>` tag is rendered via jquery like this

```
 EntryElm[0].id = list[i].id; 
 EntryElm[0].type = list[i].type;
```

Comment: Can you provide sample code?

Comment: Use `data-` attributes for custom values.

Comment: Also, what error is it throwing? HTML shouldn't *throw errors*

Comment: you mean that you used custom attributes for the <li> tag like <li custom="value1">? You should use data-attributes when using custom attributes in html tags like <li data-customattr="value1">

Comment: Seems to be working in my IE10 in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/wz4Yn/

Comment: You are modifying not `type` attribute but `type` property which is not right. You should stick to answer by @kaspars-ozols below and access `data-*` attributes with `$.attr()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You should use atributes that start with "data-".

```
<li class="user" data-name="John Resig" data-city="Boston"
    data-lang="js" data-food="Bacon">
  <b>John says:</b> <span>Hello, how are you?</span>
</li>
```

Take a look here:
http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

And [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) is link to the topic in HTML5 specs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

If I change it as custom attribute, it needs major changes in my code.

As I am rendering the `<li>` tag from jquery, I replaced this code

```
EntryElm[0].type = list[i].type;
```

with this

```
EntryElm.attr('type', list[i].type)
```

After that it works fine for me in IE 10.